# Debugging H264 video issues in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, debug, h.264

I have a video stream encoded in H264 video format. The video stream is sent using RTP to the Kurento relay server. From Kurento it is sent to the browser using WebRTC. I adjusted  the Kurento configuration in a way, that it prevents transcoding from H264 to VP8 to save CPU resources.

The problem is, that the video *sometimes* does not show in Firefox (just black screen). It *always* works in Chrome, in Firefox it appears only in about 30% cases. The data are flowing OK. There is no clear pattern.

I think that it has to do something with the video format (maybe some profile/keyframes/level settings), but by trial and error I was not able to pinpoint the problem.

Is there any way how to get detailed debug information about video decoding in Firefox? I hope there will be some useful information.

Answer (score -1):

For me, this was solved by resetting the Firefox settings (`about:config`).
I went to `about:support` and clicked the button: "Refresh Firefox".